# Delete match line and required lines

Tags: linux, awk, sed

i have a text files like

```
DATA SENT TO : 1
DATA SENT TO : 2
DATA SENT TO : 3
DATA SENT TO : 4
DATA SENT TO : 5
Failed to sent data 
DATA SENT TO : 6
Failed to sent data   
DATA SENT TO : 7
Failed to sent data  
DATA SENT TO : 8
DATA SENT TO : 9
  % SENT    % FAILED    AVG   Time    Time   Time    Current
                       Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  
  0            0           0        0      0      0         0
DATA SENT TO : 10
  % SENT    % FAILED    AVG   Time    Time     Time  Current
                        Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  
  0            0           0        0      0      0         0
DATA SENT TO : 11
  % SENT    % FAILED    AVG   Time    Time     Time  Current
                        Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  
  0            0           0        0      0      0         0
DATA SENT TO : 12
  % SENT    % FAILED    AVG   Time    Time     Time  Current
                        Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  
  0            0           0        0      0      0         0
DATA SENT TO : 13
Failed to sent 
DATA SENT TO : 14
DATA SENT TO : 15
```

form the text file i need find out total count of data sent.
if i tried to use: wc -l file.txt  then it will give total line count. but it is not accurate count As i need output as

```
DATA SENT TO : 1
DATA SENT TO : 2
DATA SENT TO : 3
DATA SENT TO : 4
DATA SENT TO : 5
DATA SENT TO : 9
DATA SENT TO : 10
DATA SENT TO : 11
DATA SENT TO : 12
DATA SENT TO : 13
DATA SENT TO : 15
```

if used the commnad sed -e /Failed/ {N; d;} --> it will delete the matched and next line but iam unable to delete the following 3 lines

```
% SENT    % FAILED    AVG   Time    Time     Time  Current
                       Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  
  0            0           0        0      0      0         0
```

Comment: @ OP: I tried to format your question, because the "tables" did not show up.

Comment: @ramkumar Did any of the solutions help you?

Comment: @ Steffen And Team, thanks i am getting the accurate count with the help of shared awk solution $ awk '/DATA SENT TO/ && !f{print} {f=/Failed to sent/}' file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if you want the lines output or a count of the lines output or both so:

```
$ awk '/DATA SENT TO/ && !f{print} {f=/Failed to sent/}' file
DATA SENT TO : 1
DATA SENT TO : 2
DATA SENT TO : 3
DATA SENT TO : 4
DATA SENT TO : 5
DATA SENT TO : 9
DATA SENT TO : 10
DATA SENT TO : 11
DATA SENT TO : 12
DATA SENT TO : 13
DATA SENT TO : 15

$ awk '/DATA SENT TO/ && !f{cnt++} {f=/Failed to sent/} END{print cnt+0}' file
11

$ awk '/DATA SENT TO/ && !f{print;cnt++} {f=/Failed to sent/} END{print "Total=" cnt+0}' file
DATA SENT TO : 1
DATA SENT TO : 2
DATA SENT TO : 3
DATA SENT TO : 4
DATA SENT TO : 5
DATA SENT TO : 9
DATA SENT TO : 10
DATA SENT TO : 11
DATA SENT TO : 12
DATA SENT TO : 13
DATA SENT TO : 15
Total=11
```

Comment: The output is just like requested. In the beginning I thought however (mistakenly), the 'Failed to sent' line would come _after_ that 'DATA SENT TO' line. And for that I couldn't find a solution in awk. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Yeah I thought that too and that was actually the first solution I posted. It's hard to read in a comment but here it is anyway: `awk '(prev ~ /DATA SENT TO/) && !/Failed to sent data/ {
    print prev
}
{ prev = $0 }
END {
    if (prev ~ /DATA SENT TO/) {
        print prev
    }
}' file`

Comment: Ah, *facepalm*. Don't know why I didn't get to that.. I ran in the direction of `getline` and tried to find out how you could get awk making a second-pass.

Comment: A second pass would be do-able but, of course, isn't necessary. If you're ever considering getline again, though, then make sure to read and fully understand http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline first so you can identify and handle the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use awk to sum the values and substract the failing lines:

```
awk '/DATA SENT TO/{sum++} /Failed to sent/{sum--} END{print sum}' test.txt
```

Comment: The `Failed to sent data` lines refer to the next line, which should be suppressed, IIUC.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^Failed to sent/N;/^DATA/p' file
```

Suppress implicit printing. Delete lines beginning `Failed to sent` and the following line. Only print lines that begin `DATA`.

To obtain the number of such lines use:

```
sed -n '/^Failed to sent/N;/^DATA/p' file | wc -l
```

Or:

```
sed -n '/^Failed to sent/N;/^DATA/p' file | sed -n '$='
```